# Query database, and pass the results to a child class in a separate file

Tags: php, arrays, oop, inheritance

I'm going out of my mind here, and I know I have asked kind of the same question before - but I plan to keep the rest of my hair.

To outline my problem: I have a class that queries the database (`QueryDB`), and stores the results as an associative array called `$data`, and another class (`DisplayTable`) that should display a table based off these results.

I can `print_r($data)` from within the class itself, but I how do I get access to the `$data` variable from a child class in a separate file? I have spent the last week trying just about everything - with or without `$this->`, making getters and setters, returns/no returns, but the array in `DisplayTable` either comes out empty or just returns NULL.

If I hardcode an array (`$defined`) in QueryDB that's identical to the results I get from the `$data` array, I can pass it just fine to the child class using `$this->defined`, so the only apparent difference between `$data` and `$defined`, is that `$data` is dynamically generated. Are those treated completely different than static ones, or am I missing some basic thing in my parent or child class(es)?

And if you could please briefly explain my error(s) instead of just saying *"you need this or that at line X"*. That doesn't help me to learn, and I really want to get better at this :)

querydb.php:

```
class QueryDB extends DBCon {

    public $q;
    public $result;
    public $data = array();
    public $defined = array(
        array(
            "id" => 1,
            "user" => "user1",
            "pass" => "pass1"),
        array(
            "id" => 2,
            "user" => "user2",
            "pass" => "pass2")
    );

    public function __construct($q) {

        $result = $this->connect()->query($q) or die("Database error");
        $numRows = $result->num_rows;

        if ( $numRows > 0 ) {

            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                $this->data[] = $row;

            }

            return $this->data;

        } else {

            echo 'No rows found.';

        }

    }

}
```

displaytable.php:

```
class DisplayTable extends QueryDB {

    public function __construct() {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($this->defined); // Returns the hardcoded array
        print_r($this->data);    // Returns an empty array
        echo '</pre>';
    }

}
```

***EDIT jan 18: Ok, after fiddling a bit, I suddenly got it to work. Probably not the optimal or correct way of doing it, but my code looks like this now:***

querydb.php:

```
class QueryDB extends DBCon {
    public $q;
    public $result;
    public $data = array();

    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function query($q) {

        $result = $this->connect()->query($q) or die("Database error");
        $numRows = $result->num_rows;

        if ( $numRows > 0 ) {

            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                $this->data[] = $row;

            }

            return $this->data;

        } else {

            echo 'No rows found.';

        }

    }

}
```

displaytable.php:

```
class DisplayTable extends QueryDB {

    public $foo;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getTable($foo) {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($foo->data);
        echo '</pre>';
    }

}
```

index.php:

```
$res    = new QueryDB();

$res->query("SELECT * FROM `testdb`");

$tab    = new DisplayTable();
$tab->getTable($res);
```

Do I understand this correct?:

1. `$res = new QueryDB();` // I instantiate the QueryDB object as `$res` in `index.php`
2. `$res->query("SELECT * FROM 'testdb'");` // I pass the query as an argument
3. In `QueryDB` class, the `$data` array gets returned: `return $this->data;`
4. `$res` now holds the `$data` array, right?
5. I instantiate the `DisplayTable()` object as `$tab` in `index.php`
6. I call the `getTable()` method using `$res` as argument
7. The `getTable()` method takes `$foo` as an placeholder argument (which in fact is `$res`)
8. I now have access to `$foo->data` / (`$res->data`)

It's probably too much back and forth, but it's the only solution I can come up with right now. Suggestions to making it simpler (if possible) are still very appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

If you override the constructor in a class that extends another class, that child constructor runs *instead of* (rather than *in addition to*) the parent class constructor. So you (usually) want to explicitly call the parent class constructor from within the child class constructor:

```
class DisplayTable extends QueryDB {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        // stuff specific to this child class
    }
}
```

That said, constructors shouldn't return anything or echo anything. They should be used only for initializing the object. Don't put the main logic for your class in the constructor, put it in a method called `query()` or something.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Alex. I tried to make a separate `query()` method like you suggested, and included the `parent::__construct()` to the child constructor. Still, the `$data` array comes out empty, whereas the `$defined` gives me output. Do I need to declare (or something?) the `$data` array in the parent's or child's constructor? Sorry for asking dumb questions, but it takes time for me to go from procedural to object oriented php...